# Ads list not showing up in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

i am creating a website using PHP and mysql...in my code, there is a list containing the images for Ads...The problem is that those images do not show up if i use in the code in php i.e. if my page is index.php and i run through wamp, but if i put the code in a simple html page like index.html, the images for ads show up....i fire bug it and found that in index.php, that ul containing ads is somehow hide...i dont know why is this behavior...Need you guidance...

Check out the screen shots

For index.php
http://zahms.com/awais/image1.png

For index.html
http://zahms.com/awais/image2.png

Note that there is some strange class which is being assigned to the li tag in index.php but that is not in my actual code..here is my code for that list....it is the same for both index.php and index.html

```
<ul class="Ads">
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad1" /></li>
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad2" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is your php code that you are using? You have not really given us a complete question to help us give you a complete answer. Need a lot more detail than two screenshots of your basic website.

Comment: We need more than screenshots. We need to see the php and html code otherwise it's like looking for a $needle in a $haystack

Comment: there is no php code i am using to show up those images...its just the extension....if i run the code through index.html then everything works fine....if i run the code through index.php.....that ul thing stops working...strange thing is that i am not using any php code to display those images....

Comment: Are your image paths correct? They vary in your both examples. Can you provide as an example page?

Comment: the image paths are correct....for index.php, i put the images in a folder named "images" for better layout but for index.html, they are in the same directory as the index.html page..so they are correct...you guys take a look that some class is being assigned to the li in index.php....there is no class anywhere in my code...

Answer (score 1):

In your index.php, you have to change the src of your images from "images/Ad.png" to "Ad.png"

```
<ul class="Ads">
<li><img src="Ad.png" alt="ad1" /></li>
<li><img src="Ad.png" alt="ad2" /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes...that worked but for that i have to place those images in the same directory as index.php but why they are not working when they are placed in the image folder, and the path is correctly given for that as i am not giving the paths for the first time but it is the first time in which i am seeing that strange class assigned to the images....

Comment: have you tried this: src="./images/Ad.png", otherwise, can you give us the styles applyed to the images, you can give us a screenshot of the inspect element on img tag.

Comment: When you changed the folder name, do you still get the strange class?

Comment: I think you have to check your javascript, if you are using any!

Comment: javascript has nothing to do with this buddy...just leave it..i got it working so we can leave it now :-)

Answer (score 0):

either you didn't close the php tags correctly, or you didn't echo it correctly:

```
<?php 
echo '<ul class="Ads">
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad1" /></li>
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad2" /></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

or just without php tags

```
<ul class="Ads">
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad1" /></li>
<li><img src="images/Ad.png" alt="ad2" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why and how the images are not working if i place them in a folder named 'images' and give the correct path as 'images/Ad.png'...i have made a new folder named 'uploads' and put the image in that folder and provided that path as 'uploads/Ad.png'....so this is still a mystery that images are not working for one folder and they are working with the same method but for the other folder...here is the code

```
 <ul class="Ads"> 
  <li><img src="uploads/Ad.png" alt="ad1" /></li>
  <li><img src="uploads/Ad.png" alt="ad2" /></li> 
  </ul>
```

And this is working guys... 
If someone found the reason, kindly tell it so that i would be careful for the next time....thanks